# Open Workbook and copy Data with Variable Ranges in both Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up this Sheet where I'll open another file using VBA copy it's contents and paste them in my main file. The thing is: both the file I'm copying information from and the one I'm pasting the information have variable ranges. This is my code so far:

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
Dim lastrowopen As Variant
Dim lastrowthis As Variant

FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename

If FiletoOpen <> False Then
Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
lastrowopen = Openbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2", "AB" & lastrowopen).Copy
lastrowthis = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base de Dados").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base de Dados").Range("A" & lastrowthis).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```

Everything works great till `lastrowthis = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base de Dados").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row` where I'm getting error 9 and I'm not sure what is wrong with it

Any advice ?

Comment: That means `ThisWorkbook` does not contain a sheet named "Base de Dados". Check spelling and spacing.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

### Workbook, Worksheet & Range

**Tips**

- Use `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare all variables.
- Use variables.
- Write step by step.
- When only values are needed, it is more efficient to just 'write' ('assign') the values.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_Data()
    
    ' Source
    Dim sFilePath As Variant: sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If sFilePath = False Then Exit Sub
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sLast As Long: sLast = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A2", "AB" & sLast)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Base de Dados")
    Dim dCell As Range:
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Assign (Write)
    dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value

End Sub
```